# REST API in node js does not respond after 10 request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting trouble to implement rest API in node js project. Currently I have implemented rest API successfully but there is an issue when I make 10 time request of any webservice. it will not respond from node server.

please help??..
thanks in advance.

Thanks for youur replay.
here is code of my webservice.
actullly  i am not using any specific rest framework in nodejs expect to express.
**Code:**

```
router.route('/changePassword').post(function(req,res){
var authkey = req.body.authkey;
var oldpassword = sha1(req.body.oldpassword);
var password = sha1(req.body.newpassword);
var organizationid = req.body.organizationid;
var userid = req.body.userid;
connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('CONNECTION error: ',err);
        res.statusCode = 503;
        res.send({
            result: 'error',
            error:    err.code
        });
    } else {
        connection.query('SELECT organizationid FROM authenticationkey WHERE authenticationkey = "'+authkey+'"', function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.send({status: '0',err:    err.code});
            }
            if(result.length > 0){
                connection.query('SELECT userid FROM users WHERE password = "'+oldpassword+'" AND organizationid = "'+organizationid+'" AND userid = "'+userid+'"', function(err, result) {
                    if(result.length > 0){
                        var update = {
                                password:password
                        };
                        connection.query('UPDATE users SET ? WHERE userid = ? AND organizationid = ?',[update,userid,organizationid], function(error, row) {
                            if(row){
                                res.send({
                                    status: '1',
                                    message:  'Password changed successfully.'
                                });
                            }else{
                                res.send({
                                    status: '-1',
                                    message:  'Password is not changed...please try again.'
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        res.send({
                            status: '-2',
                            message: 'Your old password is incorrect.'
                        });
                    }
                    //connection.release();
                });
            }else{
                res.send({
                    status: '0',
                    error: 'Authentication key is invalid.'
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

**End**
Also this my route configuration that i am using for url

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //parses information from POST
var cn = require('./../db');
var connectionpool = cn.open();
var sha1 = require('sha1');
var http = require("http");
// for file upload
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path'),
// Get parent directory
directory = path.dirname(module.parent.filename);
var parent = path.resolve(directory, '..');
var uploaddir = parent + (path.sep) +'images' + (path.sep) + 'users' + (path.sep);
var thumbdir = parent + (path.sep) +'images' + (path.sep) + 'users' + (path.sep)+ 'thumb' + (path.sep);
var imageurl = "/images/users/thumb/";
var dirpath = "/images/users/";
```

Comment: Where is the code ? how could we help you without code ?

Comment: Please add the code you are referring to.

Comment: Please provide more information as well as the code

Comment: Let me guess: your connection pool has a size of 10?

Comment: yes, i can make request just 10 time. when i am not configure any parameters for connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're using [`node-mysql` connection pooling](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) (please mention that in your question).

The documentation states:

> When you are done with a connection, just call `connection.release()` and the connection will return to the pool, ready to be used again by someone else.

You don't seem to be releasing the connections you get from the pool (in fact, it's commented out at some point).

Also, the [pool options documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pool-options) states:

> `connectionLimit`: The maximum number of connections to create at once. (Default: `10`)

Since you're not releasing your connections anywhere, after 10 requests a subsequent call to `connectionpool.getConnection()` will wait until a connection becomes available. Which is never, since you're not releasing them.

Also, your code is susceptible to SQL injections (`authkey`, `organizationid` and `userid` are passed unescaped). You need to [properly escape](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) all user-supplied input, or use placeholders.

Comment: thanks for you help. its really appreciated . do you how to configure maximum number of connections unlimited.???

Comment: @DhavalKanojiya try setting `connectionLimit` to `Infinity` (however, I don't think you actually want that).